# Virtualhost subdomain Internal Server Error

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost

I am trying to set up user generated sub domains for my PHP application.

When I go to **sub.domain.com** and if I upload an index.html file it works fine, however if I use index.php it gives me a "Internal Server Error 500" message

I have done the steps below to get subdomains working

**STEP 1:**

Edited my DNZ zone file and appended *.domain.com.      IN  A    91.111.111.111

**STEP 2:**

Appended to httpd.conf the following:

```
<VirtualHost 91.111.111.111:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias *.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/domain/public_html/sub
    <Directory "/home/domain/public_html/sub">
        Options -Indexes 
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Step 3:**

Tested by uploading an index.html file to the document directory in step 2, and works fine. Tried with an index.php gives a internal server error and then I looked into Apache error log and shows error for a redirect loop more than 10 times

Update: getting this error:

**No user or group set - set suPHP_UserGroup**

Any ideas why I can not use any .php file in the directory?

Comment: why is your DNS config for `91.11.111.111` and your virthost for `192.111.111.111`? totally different IPs...

Comment: Ignore that, the IP is correct, just updated it

Comment: got any mod_rewrite stuff elsewhere? Can't see how this code would be causing redirects.

Comment: Nope. Could it be that the .php file is not being interepreted as a index file for some reason? Would there be some PHP configuration needed so sub domains can process .php?

Comment: Try removing `index.html` from the folder. That may be the reason for the endless loop.

Comment: .php not being executed wouldn't cause a redirect, you'd just get the php code as text in your browser, or offered up as a download.

Comment: removed it and just have the index.php but still getting the error

Comment: Check your logs again then, see if there's more in it that you can tell us.

Comment: If you remove `.htaccess` and remove that condition in `httpd.conf` can you run `.php` files?

Comment: I am gettting this error now: [Tue Aug 26 01:19:09 2014] [error] [client 91.111.111.111] No user or group set - set suPHP_UserGroup

Comment: Have you tried an empty .php file? Because so far we don't know if maybe your index.php is simply broken and your php parser complaining with a 500.

Edit: just saw your last reply. It already tells you the issue. You are using suPHP but haven't configured it properly thus the php execution fails.

Comment: The error message already tells you what to do: “set `suPHP_UserGroup`”